# OpenAI Text-To-Speech API - NodeJS - How To Get A base64 Payloads Back

Tags: node.js, base64, openai-api

I am using the OpenAI Text-To-Speach API as shown below and it works fine. It will build am MP3 and save on the server. But I need to have the audio in base64 format so that I can save it in a database and use it on a websocket. Currently OpenAI saves as MP3 or Flac and then I convirt to .wav then to base64 all in NodeJS. This all works but I want to make it more streamlined.

Is there a way to get base64 direct from the OpenAI Text-To-Speach API without having to build an MP3 file and save it?

```
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import OpenAI from "openai";
const openai = new OpenAI();

const speechFile = path.resolve("./speech.mp3");

async function main() {
  const mp3 = await openai.audio.speech.create({
    model: "tts-1",
    voice: "alloy",
    input: "Today is a wonderful day to build something people love!",
  });
  console.log(speechFile);
  const buffer = Buffer.from(await mp3.arrayBuffer());
  await fs.promises.writeFile(speechFile, buffer);
}
main();
```